# How to get the pandas query statement to work for to_datetime and to_timedelta?

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to filter my dataframe so that I get only the rows with the latest 2 days of data (relative to the latest available date from the dataframe). So this code would work:

`df[pd.to_datetime(df['date']) <= pd.to_datetime(df['date'].max()) - pd.to_timedelta('2 days')]`

But now I would like to achieve this same effect but using the `query` method. But if I do this:

`df.query("@pd.to_datetime(quote_date) <= @pd.to_datetime(quote_date.max()) - @pd.to_timedelta('2 days')")`

then I get `TypeError: Cannot convert input [2 days 00:00:00] of type <class 'pandas._libs.tslibs.timedeltas.Timedelta'> to Timestamp` error.

I can't get this thing to work, and would love to get some feedbacks on what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: What is it you are specifically trying to do?  Giving us code that doesn't work and asking us to fix it without knowing the desired result isn't how I work!!!!

Comment: My apologies, I should've been more specific in my question. I revised my question to be more specific.

Comment: Your question needs a minimal reproducible example consisting of sample input, expected output, actual output, and only the relevant code necessary to reproduce the problem. See [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) for best practices related to Pandas questions.